# Kthread and Schedule() slowing down the code. OR how to sleep in kernel

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, linux-device-driver, interrupt

Using module_init I have created and woken up a kthread. In order to keep it alive and also do my function task, I used the following approach. That was the only approach I could make it running since I am changing the flag in an interrupt. Now I am facing an unbelievably drop in the performance of the code. I narrowed down a problem to the following piece of code:

```
   while(1){            
        //Do my tasks here after changing flag  

        while(get_flag() ){ //Waiting for a flag, to basically do my Func in the previous line.
              schedule();       
        }       
   }//to keep a kthread alive after initial create.
```

Details about dropping the performance: without using the second while(1) which includes schedule, the rate of data transmission in my code is 35MB/s but with this little line, it drops to 5MB/s.

Is there any other way that I can make a kthread sleep and wait for a flag change?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, This is not the way you should do this in Kernel. But if you have to do it this way. 
See if you are doing a blocking check for the flag? If that is the case, change it to non-blocking wait, just check for the flag and schedule that should be enough in most of the cases. The scheduling algorithm will make sure to get the fair share of CPU for all the processes. Also, if you are doing a blocking check for flag you are unnecessarily wasting CPU cycles since you are doing the processing only on the next scheduler slice. with the same logic, if you want to get better performance, you should wake up your waiting process from your producer thread with wakeup_task()

-or-

if you just want to achieve the functionality, I feel the right way to do it is the following method. using a wait queue, wait_even_interruptible() and wake_up_interruptible()

From your above said kernel thread you just need to call the wait_event_interruptible 
see the pseudo code below

```
while (1){
wait_event_interruptible(wq, your_flag)
{
<do your task>
}
}
```

and from the place you are setting the flag

```
{
<some event> 
<set flag>
wake_up_interruptible (wq)
}
```

You don't have to call the schedule explicitly.

Comment: @Hamed your problem is your task is sleeping too much. That means, since you are unconditionally scheduling, the task will wake up next time on regular scheduler kickin. You should have some way to wake up your process when the condition is set. This can be done only from the other task where your flag is set/unset. I have edited my answe adding some pseudo codes.

Comment: Thank you very much for all this. I have edited my code as you said and using this http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-2 . But now I have nothing in my output! Do you think the reason could be be cause I'm already in an interrupt while changing the flag?

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing in output"? What is the expected o/p? how are you dealing with it? before all these, are you able to wake up the sleeping process from the producer thread?

Comment: The output is simply a printk where you mentioned <do your task>. without this edit, I had printk working. So I assume only wake_up_interruptible and wait_event_interruptible are not working. As I said, I also followed the link. Any hint?

Comment: ok, so that means the wake up is not waking up the sleeping guy, right? This is a simple logic and I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work. Make sure you are doing all the wq inits properly. And make sure you are setting/unsetting your flag properly from both the places before/after waking up. The wait_event will check the condition, if its not evaluated true, thread will not wakeup.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was about using module init. I called it in the wrong place. On the other hand, the speed raised up to 14MB/s , still far from 35.